# Layer model expects 3 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors - Error raised when trying to fit the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, text-classification, keras-layer, bert-language-model

I am doing a simple cyberbullying detection model using BERT embeddings and TensorFlow. My dataset has two columns (label and text). It is a binary classification problem since 0 means a tweet is harassing and 1 is neutral. 
You can find the altered_data dataset that I am using [here](https://archive.org/details/altered_data). The original dataset can be found [here](https://github.com/t-davidson/hate-speech-and-offensive-language/tree/master/data).
Following the [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/official_models/fine_tuning_bert) for fine-tuning BERT, I have built the following model:

```
!git clone --depth 1 -b v2.3.0 https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
!pip install -Uqr models/official/requirements.txt
```

After this, a runtime restart is required. Then the following code is executed.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('models')
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as tf_hub

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn

from official.nlp.data import classifier_data_lib
from official.nlp.bert import tokenization
from official.nlp import optimization
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('altered_data.csv', encoding='utf-8')
train_df, remaining = train_test_split(df, random_state=42, train_size=0.90, stratify=df.sentiment.values)
valid_df, _ = train_test_split(remaining, random_state=42, train_size=0.90, stratify=remaining.sentiment.values)
train_df.shape, valid_df.shape
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
  train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_df['sentiment'].values, train_df['tweet'].values))
  valid_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((valid_df.sentiment.values, valid_df.tweet.values))

  for label, text in train_data.take(1):
    print(label)
    print(text)

  for label, text in valid_data.take(1):
    print(label)
    print(text)  

label_list = [0, 1]
max_seq_length = 128
train_batch_size = 32

bert_layer = tf_hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/2", trainable=True)

vocab_file = bert_layer.resolved_object.vocab_file.asset_path.numpy()
do_lower_case = bert_layer.resolved_object.do_lower_case.numpy()
tokenizer = tokenization.FullTokenizer(vocab_file, do_lower_case)

def to_feature(text, label, label_list=label_list, max_seq_length=max_seq_length, tokenizer=tokenizer):
  example = classifier_data_lib.InputExample(guid=None, 
                                             text_a = text.numpy(),
                                             text_b = None, 
                                             label = label.numpy())
  feature = classifier_data_lib.convert_single_example(0, example, label_list, max_seq_length, tokenizer)

  return (feature.input_ids, feature.input_mask, feature.segment_ids, feature.label_id)

def to_feature_map(label, text):
  input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, label_id = tf.py_function(to_feature, inp=[label, text], 
                                                                Tout=[tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32])
  input_ids.set_shape([max_seq_length])
  input_mask.set_shape([max_seq_length])
  segment_ids.set_shape([max_seq_length])
  label_id.set_shape([])

  x = {
      'input_word_ids': input_ids,
       'input_mask': input_mask,
       'input_type_ids': segment_ids
  }

  return (label, x)

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
  train_data = (train_data.map(to_feature_map,
                               num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
  .shuffle(1000)
  .batch(32, drop_remainder=True)
  .prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE))

  valid_data = (valid_data.map(to_feature_map,
                               num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
  .batch(32, drop_remainder=True)
  .prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE))
```

Train Data tensor spec

```
train_data.element_spec
```

[image: tensorSpecResult]

Create model code:

```
def create_model():
  input_word_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), dtype=tf.int32,
                                         name="input_word_ids")
  input_mask = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), dtype=tf.int32,
                                         name="input_mask")
  input_type_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), dtype=tf.int32,
                                         name="input_type_ids")
  
  pooled_output, sequence_output = bert_layer([input_word_ids, input_mask, input_type_ids])
  drop = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4)(pooled_output)
  output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name="output")(drop)

  model = tf.keras.Model(
      inputs={
          'input_word_ids': input_word_ids, 
          'input_mask': input_mask,
          'input_type_ids': input_type_ids
      }, outputs=output)
  return model 

model = create_model()
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=2e-5),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()])
model.summary()
```

[image: model summary]
[image: index]

```
epoch = 4
history = model.fit(train_data, 
                    validation_data=valid_data, 
                    epochs=epoch,
                    verbose=1)
```

**Raises the following error:**

[image: error1]
[image: error2]

I am still a beginner in TensorFlow. To my understanding, there is a problem between the dropout and dense layers, while getting the inputs. However, I can't figure out what needs to be done in order to fix this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please post the [***minimum***](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) amount of code necessary to reproduce your issue. Please post the errors directly into the question and not as screenshots.

Comment: @gobrewers14 Thanks for the feedback. I have edited the post and added the full code. You can also download the altered dataset that I am using for this model.